# Such a low success rate with this script

Tags: javascript, error-suppression

The script itself works fine and all; it is errorless. However, out of running 7,500 times, only 35 were successful. How would I improve the success rate of Regex? Because right now, it is not doing the job.

```
var IDs = [136758649, 116770724, 136171998]//A lot more IDS than this
var PriceWanting = 60
var scanneditems = 0
var itemerror = 0
document.write('<p id = "title">Total number bought: 0 items for a total of 0</p>')
document.write('<p id = "scanned">Items scanned: 0</p>')
document.write('<p id = "itemerrors">Items scanned: 0</p>')
var buys = 0
var totalrobuxspent = 0
console.log("Bot started")
var loop = setInterval(function()
{
  for (var i = 0;i<IDs.length;i++) {
  $.get(" http://m.roblox.com/items/" + IDs[i] + "/privatesales",function(data) {
      var Regex = /\<span class="currency-robux">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/;
      var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex);
      scanneditems = scanneditems + 1
      document.getElementById("scanned").innerHTML = "Scanned items: " + scanneditems
      PriceSelling = PriceSelling ? PriceSelling[1] : '';
      if (PriceSelling.length < 1) {
        itemerrors = itemerrors + 1
        document.getElementById(''itemserror'').innerHTML = ''Total errors: '' + itemerrors
        return
      }
      PriceSelling = Number(PriceSelling.replace(",",""))
      PriceSelling = PriceSelling * 1
      totalrobuxspent = totalrobuxspent + PriceSelling
      var remaining = PriceWanting - PriceSelling
      if (remaining >= -0.1) 
      {
        buys = buys + 1
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Total number of items bought: " + buys + " for a total of " + totalrobuxspent + " "
var Regex2 = /<a href="\/Catalog\/VerifyTransfer\DuserAssetOptionId=([\d,]+)\Damp;expectedPrice=([\d,]+)">/
                                var HatBuyId = data.match(Regex2)[1]
                                var HatBuyLink = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=" + HatBuyId + " &type=robux&expectedPrice=" + PriceSelling
var Explorer = document.createElement('iframe');
                                function Buy(){
       Explorer.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
       console.log("Item purchase complete, scanning again.")
       var inf = document.createElement('div');
       inf.style.fontSize = "18px";
       inf.style.background = "rgba(0,0,5,0)";
       inf.style.position = "absolute";
       inf.style.width = "100%";
       inf.style.height = "18pt";
       inf.innerText = "Bot currently running. Purchases: "+answer;
       document.body.appendChild(inf);
                                };
                                Explorer.onload = Buy;
                                Explorer.width = "100%";
                                Explorer.height = "85%";
                                Explorer.src = HatBuyLink;
                                document.body.innerHTML = "";
                                document.body.appendChild(Explorer);
    }
  })
}
},500)
```

Comment: Please contribute a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so we can visualize the example.

Comment: There, I added the main part.

Comment: Just put `return` there, jeez. What would `continue` mean there anyway?

Comment: I read on a giant scripting site that it would just skip over the i thingy in the for loop.

Comment: That is indeed what continue should do. Return does something totally different.

What is the exact error that you are getting @user3341815? And does it work in browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: You're no longer inside that outer loop when you're handling the AJAX response. It has already ended. Are you trying to abort all further AJAX requests?

Comment: You can't have a `continue` in the body of the callback function because `continue`s are for loops, not functions. You can use a `return` there to skip the rest of that function.

Comment: It just said that the continue statement was Illegal.

Comment: @user3341815 indeed, it was

Comment: @JimmySawczuk oh good call, I didn't notice the function call there. Write that up as an answer!

Comment: Why do you hate semicolons so much, OP?

Answer (score 2):

`.get` is asynchronous.  This means that the callback function is not executed until the response is returned.  By that point, you are no longer in a loop and in fact the loop has already completed.

Though it's about a slightly different problem, [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) is a very good read to understand how asynchronous calls work.

---

In addition, `continue` here would still be illegal, even without the asynchronous behavior, because the function has its own context and is not in the same context as the loop.  This simple example would also be illegal and may be easier to understand the context issue:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    someFunc();
}

function someFunc(){
    continue;  // illegal
}
```

Though in your case the function is an anonymous function, the same concept applies.

Comment: It's more a question of context than order of execution, I believe, but this is largely correct.

Comment: This answer is correct; the OP could use `return;` instead of `continue;` to achieve the same result though; terminating that ajax handler due to bad data.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk Technically, yes.  But in terms of understanding, the OP clearly thinks that these callbacks are being called in sequence, hence the belief that continue will move on to the next iteration of the loop.  Let me reword a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use semicolons in your code.

```
continue;
```

is applicable in loops, not in functions. Use the

```
return;
```

keyword to get out of the context of a function.